# Javascript: alternative or less complex code to create hidden input forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I ask for your help to improve the form I created, keeping in mind that I am not a great expert in javascript programming.

I need to create a hotel search engine, with the possibility to choose the total number of rooms. Depending on the number of rooms selected, as many hidden form fields will be displayed, containing additional selection fields.

To make the idea of ​​what I have created better, I attach a screen.

[image]

To view the hidden fields in relation to the number of rooms chosen, I used this javascript code, repeated 5 times (maximum number of rooms).

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
console.log(nameSelect);
if(nameSelect){
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("room1").value;
    if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
        document.getElementById("pax_room_1").style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("pax_room_1").style.display = "none";
    }
}
else{
    document.getElementById("pax_room_1").style.display = "none";
}
```

To realize the options for choosing each room, I used this javascript code repetition in proportion to the room number. That is: 1 room -> entered code 1 once; 2 rooms -> entered the code 2 times; etc.

```
function childSelect(nameSelect)
{
console.log(nameSelect);
if(nameSelect){
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("child1").value;
    if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
        document.getElementById("agechild1").style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("agechild1").style.display = "none";
    }
 }
 else{
    document.getElementById("agechild1").style.display = "none";
 }

 if(nameSelect){
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("child2").value;
    if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
        document.getElementById("agechild2").style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("agechild2").style.display = "none";
    }
}
else{
    document.getElementById("agechild2").style.display = "none";
}

if(nameSelect){
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("child3").value;
    if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
        document.getElementById("agechild3").style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("agechild3").style.display = "none";
    }
}
else{
    document.getElementById("agechild3").style.display = "none";
}
}

$(function(){
     $(':submit').click(function(){
          $('select').each(function(){
              if ( $(this).val() == '' )
              {
                  $(this).remove(); // or 
$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
              }
          });
     });
});
```

While, I used this html code repeated the same way.

```
<div class="container_hidden">


    <div id="pax_room_1" style="display:none;" class="row_hidden">

        <div class="nrRoom" style="width: 100px;background: #f5a445;font-size: 15px;text-align: center;height: 30px; padding-top: 5px; border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;"><font color="#000"><img src="images/family-room.png" alt="Icon Family Room" style="width: 19px;" /> Room 1</font></div>

            <div class="column"><font color="#000">Adult (18+)</font>
                <select id="adulti" name="nrAdult">
                    <option value="">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>        
                </select>
            </div>          
            <div class="column"><font color="#000">Children (0-17)</font>
                <select id="nrchild" name="nrChild" onchange="childSelect(this);">
                    <option value="">-</option>
                    <option id="child1" value="1">1</option>
                    <option id="child2" value="2">2</option>
                    <option id="child3" value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                        <!-- Select Bambino 1 -->
                        <div id="agechild1" style="display:none;" class="row_hidden">
                        <div class="column"><font color="#000"> Child Age 1 </font>
                        <select id="child1" name="ageChild1">
                        <option value="">-</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Select Bambino 1-2 -->
                        <div id="agechild2" style="display:none;" class="row_hidden">
                        <div class="column"><font color="#000"> Child Age 1 </font>
                        <select id="child1" name="ageChild1">
                        <option value="">-</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column"><font color="#000"> Child Age 2 </font>
                        <select id="child2" name="ageChild2">
                        <option value="">-</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Select Bambino 1-2-3 -->
                        <div id="agechild3" style="display:none;" class="row_hidden">
                        <div class="column"><font color="#000"> Child Age 1 </font>
                        <select id="child1" name="ageChild1">
                        <option value="">-</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column"><font color="#000"> Child Age 2 </font>
                        <select id="child2" name="ageChild2">
                        <option value="">-</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column"><font color="#000"> Child Age 3 </font>
                        <select id="child3" name="ageChild3">
                        <option value="">-</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
```

I realize that it is too laborious, even if it works. This is why I ask you if there is a way to lighten the code.

Comment: Please direct this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data-*` attribute to dynamically choose the relations in the html.

e.g.

```js
(function() {
  const hiders = document.getElementsByClassName('hider');
  // const is ES6 syntax, you can use var, although you might want to read up on that

  for (let i = 0; i < hiders.length; ++i) {
    const hider = hiders[i];

    hider.onchange = function() {
      const hideTarget = hider.dataset.hideTarget; // this reads the value of data-hide-target

      if (hideTarget == null)
        return; // no target set (else we would potentially get an TypeError, when data-hide-target wasn't set. Still happens with an invalid value though, but there you want an error

      if (hider.value !== '')
        document.getElementById(hideTarget).style.display = "block";
      else
        document.getElementById(hideTarget).style.display = "none";
      // you might also want to take a look at .setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true") and .style.visibility = "hidden"
    };
  }
})()
```

```html
<select id="adulti" name="nrAdult" class="hider" data-hide-target="hideme1">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>        
</select>

<div id="hideme1" style="display: none;">
  Hide me 1
</div>

<select id="adulti2" name="nrAdult" class="hider" data-hide-target="hideme2">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>        
</select>

<div id="hideme2" style="display: none;">
  Hide me 2
</div>
```

I think this snippet is rather easy to understand, but if you want me to elaborate a bit further, feel free to ask.

---

FYI, this can also be used for convenience in this example:

```js
(function(){
  function makeOption(val) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = val;
    option.innerText = val;
    return option;
  }

  const simpleSelects = document.getElementsByClassName('simpleSelect');
  for(let i = 0; i < simpleSelects.length; ++i){
    const simpleSelect = simpleSelects[i];
    const min = simpleSelect.dataset.from;
    const max = simpleSelect.dataset.to;
    
    if(min == null || max == null)
      return;
      
    simpleSelect.appendChild(makeOption('-'));
    
    for (let j = min; j <= max; ++j) {
      simpleSelect.appendChild(makeOption(j));
    }
  }
})()
```

```html
<select name="nrAdult" class="simpleSelect" data-from="0" data-to="5"></select>
<select name="nrChildren" class="simpleSelect" data-from="0" data-to="10"></select>
```

---

And I also just realised that you were using the same id multiple times, which is not only not allowed, but also doesn't work.

(And yes I am aware that what this does is quite different from what you want, but it is the same principle and I didn't want to give you an out-of-the-box solution.)